# Handling HUGE numbers in numpy or pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am doing a competition where I am provided data that is anonymized. Quite a few of the columns have HUGE values. The largest was 40 digits long! I used `pd.read_csv` but those columns have been converted to objects as a result.

My original plan was to scale the data down but since they are seen as objects I can't do arithmetic on these.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to handle huge numbers in Pandas or Numpy?

Note that I've tried converting the value to a `uint64` with no luck. I get the error "long too big to convert"

Comment: Are those 40 digit values really numeric data, or are they ID strings?

Comment: Are the HUGE values integer or float?

Comment: @Marius *Apparently* they are numerical data. The forums for the competition had the same question but the moderator said that it was to be treated as numerical. dawg the huge values are integers

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.  You can do arithmetic on dtype=object columns if the objects are large integers.

Comment: @DSM it looks like some of the long numbers are treated as strings so it won't allow arithmetic

Comment: are you working on the Kaggle "loan" competition?  If so, I read in those same fields by passing `dtype=float64` to `pd.read_csv`. I was having issues storing these long columns as objects in the HDFStore on disk. I think because of the mixed types...

Comment: @Zelazny7 yup I'm doing that competition...First the size of the data, was an issue, then the types, but finally I am getting somewhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Pandas [converters](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) to call `int` or some other custom converter function on the string as they are being imported:

```
import pandas as pd 
from StringIO import StringIO

txt='''\
line,Big_Num,text
1,1234567890123456789012345678901234567890,"That sure is a big number"
2,9999999999999999999999999999999999999999,"That is an even BIGGER number"
3,1,"Tiny"
4,-9999999999999999999999999999999999999999,"Really negative"
'''

df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), converters={'Big_Num':int})

print df
```

Prints:

```
   line                                    Big_Num                           text
0     1   1234567890123456789012345678901234567890      That sure is a big number
1     2   9999999999999999999999999999999999999999  That is an even BIGGER number
2     3                                          1                           Tiny
3     4  -9999999999999999999999999999999999999999                Really negative
```

Now test arithmetic:

```
n=df["Big_Num"][1]
print n,n+1
```

Prints:

```
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

If you have any values in the column that might cause `int` to croak, you can do this:

```
txt='''\
line,Big_Num,text
1,1234567890123456789012345678901234567890,"That sure is a big number"
2,9999999999999999999999999999999999999999,"That is an even BIGGER number"
3,0.000000000000000001,"Tiny"
4,"a string","Use 0 for strings"
'''

def conv(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            return 0        

df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), converters={'Big_Num':conv})
print df
```

Prints:

```
   line                                   Big_Num                           text
0     1  1234567890123456789012345678901234567890      That sure is a big number
1     2  9999999999999999999999999999999999999999  That is an even BIGGER number
2     3                                     1e-18                           Tiny
3     4                                         0              Use 0 for strings
```

Then every value in the column will be either a Python int or a float and will support arithmetic.

Comment: after some thought I've decided to accept your answer. DSM's answer is accurate, but your answer is both accurate and allows me to deal with NaNs. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If you have a mixed-type column -- some integers, some strings -- stored in a dtype=object column, you can still convert to ints and perform arithmetic.  Starting from a mixed-type column:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [11**44, "11"*22]})
>>> df
                                                A
0  6626407607736641103900260617069258125403649041
1    11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

[2 rows x 1 columns]
>>> df.dtypes, list(map(type, df.A))
(A    object
dtype: object, [<type 'long'>, <type 'str'>])
```

We can convert to ints:

```
>>> df["A"] = df["A"].apply(int)
>>> df.dtypes, list(map(type, df.A))
(A    object
dtype: object, [<type 'long'>, <type 'long'>])
>>> df
                                                A
0  6626407607736641103900260617069258125403649041
1    11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

[2 rows x 1 columns]
```

And then perform arithmetic:

```
>>> df // 11
                                               A
0  602400691612421918536387328824478011400331731
1    1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101

[2 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: @DSM Thank you I will review this answer when I get home later tonight

Comment: Ach no. Seems no longer to work as shown. apply(int) delivers dtype object?

Comment: regarding. pandas.to_numeric: "Due to internal limitations of ndarray... precision loss may occur... if really large numbers are passed in... numbers larger than 18446744073709551615". My own numbers longer than this one begat objects when applied with int. (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)

Answer (score 3):

Edit: These can't be (accurately) represented as floats either, it just doesn't raise when you try... probably best to use object dtype and longs as in DSM's answer.

But you can do it inaccurately (using @DSM's example):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [11**44, "11"*22]}).astype(float)

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
              A
0  6.626408e+45
1  1.111111e+43

[2 rows x 1 columns]

In [13]: df.dtypes
Out[13]: 
A    float64
dtype: object
```

But it may not be what you want...

```
In [21]: df.iloc[0, 0]
Out[21]: 6.6264076077366411e+45

In [22]: long(df.iloc[0, 0])
Out[22]: 6626407607736641089115845702792172379125579776L

In [23]: 11 ** 44
Out[23]: 6626407607736641103900260617069258125403649041L
```

As DSM suggests, convert to long (and use object dtype) so as not to lose accuracy:

```
In [31]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [11**44, "11"*22]}).apply(long, 1)

In [32]: df
Out[32]: 
0    6626407607736641103900260617069258125403649041
1      11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
dtype: object
```

Comment: wow I'm shocked that we could change it to float and have it working...I am accepting your answer because yours was the simplest  and with the scientific notation makes things much easier to read. Thank you!

Comment: Of course you know that a 40 digit string of integers cannot be fully represented in a float, right?

Comment: @dawg Thank you for noticing that. I've accepted DSMs answer instead since that preserves accuracy