# Python: Pandas and BigFloat

Tags: python, pandas, bigfloat

I have a pandas data frame with columns of data type float64.

I would like to increase the floating point precision to 200. I know you can do this with the BigFloat library.

I'm not sure what's the best way to increase the precision for floating point numbers in pandas.

Comment: So does `df.astype(BigFloat)` work?

Comment: I just installed this library and my previous comment seemed to work

Comment: It works but with decimal I can't install BigFloat.

Comment: I can't help with that as I've never used it, sounds like the libraries are conflicting. Are you able to just convert specific columns?

Comment: You might want to do some searching on BigInteger questions and pandas, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373134/pandas-python-reading-and-working-on-java-biginteger-large-numbers/31881284#31881284  I think you'll hit similar problems in that when you get away from standard int32/int64/float64/etc. you really lose a lot of the advantages of pandas as it will store big ints or floats as objects.  You can still use pandas of course, it's just some speed and convenience will be lost relative to float64 and such.

Comment: From your comment, is the problem that you can't install BigFloat?