# Create dataframe of too long integers

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create dataframe which should contain very long integer. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789, 
123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789]
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
print(df)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/watson/Desktop/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", 
line 330, in __init__
    copy=copy)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", 
line 463, in _init_ndarray
    values = _prep_ndarray(values, copy=copy)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", 
line 5578, in _prep_ndarray
    values = convert(values)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", 
line 5567, in convert
    return maybe_convert_platform(v)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 47, in 
maybe_convert_platform
    values = lib.maybe_convert_objects(values)
File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1165, in 
pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_objects (pandas/_libs/lib.c:58498)
    OverflowError: long int too large to convert
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591109/handling-huge-numbers-in-numpy-or-pandas

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the error by setting `dtype=object`. In addition, you have a typo in your example and are passing the wrong shape data given that you are specifying two columns. The following line works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=cols, dtype=object)
```

Note: I wrapped your data in a list to make it the correct dimensions. If I don't do that, it gives the `OverflowError`, even though it should really give a `ValueError` about the shape of the passed values.

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=cols, dtype=object)

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
                                            Col1  \
0  123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789

                                            Col2
0  123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789
```