# How to handle and manipulate large IDs with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently working with a database table that has an ID as primary key which can have up to 28 digits.
For my use case I need to manipulate some data points in this table (including the ID) and write it back to the db table.

Now, for the ID I need to increment it by one and I'm struggling to achieve this with pandas and windows.
Unfortunately and obviously, I cannot read and save the ID as plain integers in the dataframe.
Converting it to np.float64 beforehand seems to be completely messing up the values.

For example:
I'm manipulating the data point with ID `2021051800100770010113340000`
If I convert the ID column to `np.float64` by explicitly providing the dtype of this column,
the ID becomes `2021051800100769903675441152.0` which seems to be a completely different number to  be.
Also I don't know if incrementing the ID column by 1 is working since the result will be same as the number above.

Is there a way to this in a proper way? The last option to me would be to convert it to a string and then change the last substring of that string. But I don't feel this would be good and clean solution. Not mentioning that I'm not sure if I can write this back to the db in that form.

edit//

Based on this suggestion (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21591439/3856569)
I edited the ID column the following way:
`df["ID"] = df["ID"].apply(int)`

and then incrementing the number.

I get the following result:

`2021051800100769903675441152` 
`2021051800100769903675441153`

So the increment seems to work now but I still see completely different numbers opposed which I was getting originally.

Comment: Then why would you convert your ID to `float`? Just use `int`. Floats are just not a good idea for an absolute, reliable value.

Comment: Before I came to know the option I posted in the edit, converting to float was the only way that was working for me to convert the automatically detected `Object` dtype to a dtype with which I could increment the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please bare with me to look at this problem from another angle. If we can understand how the ID is formed, we may be able to handle it differently, for example, the first 8 digits looks like a date, and if that is true, then any of your manipulation shouldn't modify those 8 digits unless your intention is to change the date. In this case, you can separate your ID (in str) into 2 parts.

`20210518` / `00100770010113340000`

Then now we only need to handle the second part which is still too large for `np.int64`. However, if you find out how it is formed, then perhaps you can further separate it and finally handle a number that can be handled by `np.int64`.

For example, would the ID be formed in this way?
`20210518` / `001` / `007` / `7001011334` / `0000`

If we can split it into segments of meaning, then we know which part we need to keep when manipulating (adding 1 in your case)

Comment: This seems very reasonable!

Comment: I see where you are going with you idea.
If there's no other option, I'll try to get that information.
In any case, how would you go on about splitting the numbers so that they can be saved as an integer?
Reading it as a string and then splitting the string via the substring method and converting the results to int?

Comment: yes, read it as string, split it using substring e.g. `[x:y]`, and only convert the part that i need to integer, then add 1, convert it back to string, and concatenate all the parts back into one string.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
But I got to know the exact structure for the IDs and manipulated exactly the way you suggested. 
Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: Thank you for the update! It's good to hear that!